# How to wrap C++ classes with Duktape

Tags: duktape

I am playing around with **Duktape** as a replacement to v8. Skimmed through the docs and managed to call **C functions** from **Javascript** and vice-versa. However it is not clear to me how to proceed when you need to access **C++** classes from JavaScript in a similar way to v8. Could someone put together a very simple example illustrating this?

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296953/export-c-class-to-duktape