# Expose C++ class using duktape

Tags: c++, templates, duktape

I am currently in the midst of building a simple game engine/basic library.
Right now, i'm working on scripting support. Since i've always liked JavaScript more than, say, Lua or Python, i thought about using that as my principle scripting language. Google V8 struck me first, with its good performance and relatively simple means of exposing a class - by the heavy usage of templates. However, i can't seem to be able to compile V8 using MinGW on windows - it just doesn't want to. Then i looked at ChaiScript, which is also very interesting - especially because it takes embedding one step forward even compared to V8. It is, however, not my first choice.

Now, my question is as follows. How can i achieve exposing a complex C++ class to duktape? I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296953/export-c-class-to-duktape) question, but it only uses a very simple foobar-like class. Say i have this class:

```
class Entity
    {
    public:
        Entity(std::string name_item)
        ~Entity();

        size_t getID();

        bool hasComponent(size_t componentid_item);
        EntityComponent* getComponent(size_t componentid_item);
        void addComponent(EntityComponent* component_item);
        EntityComponent* removeComponent(size_t componentid_item);
        void deleteComponent(size_t componentid_item);
    private:
        unsigned long long m_ID;
        std::unordered_map<size_t, EntityComponent*> m_Components;
    };
```

How would i go about exposing it, so it can be used by duktape?
Also, can i somehow automate (or make it easier) this process by using templates, like ChaiScript (especially) and Google V8 so heavily do?

Comment: I am aware of the fact that i would have to expose all types in this, so this example probably isn't as good as i thought.

Comment: What is `duktape` (duck typing) ?

Comment: oh sorry, i thought you would know. Take a look at the tags :) its api is very similar to Luas C API, i reckon.

Comment: Still nothing? :( oh man guess ill have to choose lua then...